Polish & tight condition is equivalent to weakly convergent condition?
I just began to study measure and probability theory. I'd like to know the proof of following quote.
My book (Feynman-Kac-Type Theorems and Gibbs Measures on Path Space) says

We will be mainly interested in the case $S=C([0,\infty]) $ and $S=C(\mathbb{R})$. Since both are Polish spaces, a family of probability measures $(S,\mathscr{B}(S))$ has a weakly convergent sequence if it is tight.

(Here, $\mathscr{B}(S)$ is Borel $\sigma$-field.)
I know the definition of (1)"weakly convergent" and (2)"tight"
$$$$
Definition
Let $S$ be a metric space and $P$ a probability measure on $(S,\mathscr{B}(S))$.
(1) A sequence of probability measures $(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ on $(S,\mathscr{B}(S))$ is weakly convergent to $P$ whenever
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}_{P_n}[f]=\mathbb{E}_P[f]$$
for every bounded and continuous real-valued function $f$ on $S$.
(Here $\mathbb{E}_P$ means expectation value about $P$.)
(2) A family $\mathscr{P} $ of probability measures on $(S,\mathscr{B}(S))$ is tight whenever for every  $\epsilon >0$ there exists a compact set $K_\epsilon \subset S$ such that $P'(K_\epsilon) >1-\epsilon$, for every $P'\in\mathscr{P}$ .
$$$$
I don't know how Polishness connects tightness with weakly convergence.  I'd like to know why a family of probability has a weak convergent sequence whenever $S$ is Polish and the family is tight.
If you have any idea, I'd like you to share it. Hint also helps.
